# Finding the user id that has loggin in angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

i create a login in angular6 and aspcore .

this is my **loginService.ts :**

```
  LoginService(login:Login){
return this.http.post<Login>(`${this.appConfig.apiEndpoint}${this.appConfig.loginPath}`,login,{headers:this.headers})
.pipe(map(respose => {
  if(!respose)
  {
    this.authStatusSource.next(false);
  }
  if (respose) {
      // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(respose));
      this.authStatusSource.next(true);
  }
  return respose;
  }));
}
```

and server return this :

```
    {
  "sub": "3002",
  "unique_name": "kia@kia.com",
  "jti": "597b383b-b5bc-46f1-939f-022b60d7de33",
  "iat": "12/12/2018 7:27:21 AM",
  "nbf": 1544599641,
  "exp": 1549783641,
  "iss": "dotnetthoughts.net",
  "aud": "dotnetthoughts.net"
}
```

and this Login.ts :

```
loginform(user:Login){

  this.loginService.LoginService(user).subscribe((data)=>{
    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl])
  });
}
```

now i need to get `sub` for find info of user . how can i do this ?

**Edit**

when i debug loginService it show me this :

```
        C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=17368 dist\out-tsc\src\app\Services\login.service.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:17368/00cf837a-4eb0-428d-8320-b468d3ccdc47
Debugger attached.
e:\MyProject\StoreAp\dist\out-tsc\src\app\Services\login.service.js:13
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
```

Comment: Where is the `userid` in the JSON response?

Comment: Try: `console.log(respose.sub)` inside second if!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I have made a mistake `sub`

Comment: Did you subscribed it somewhere?

Comment: @Jai yes . in loginComponent

Comment: Show loginComponent code!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i show code in questoin

Comment: Try my posted answer!

Comment: can I see the interface/view-model `Login`? Does it have `sub` as a key?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
this.LoginService(login).subscribe((data)=>{
   localStorate.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

When you want to use the `localStorage` use this code below :

```
let userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
console.log('userInfo : ', userInfo);
console.log('userId : ', userInfo.sub);
```

Comment: i using this : `console.log('userId : ',JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).sub)` but it show me `userid : undefinde`

Comment: What is your output when use `console.log('sub: ', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")));`

Comment: output : `userid : undefinde`

Comment: So, your `localStrorage` is not set correctly, Be sure about that first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185115/discussion-between-kianoush-and-farhad-lavaei).

Comment: i find the answer . i decode the jwt token and i can access the id , but i have question about that , this way is secure ?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have set the item in local Storage memory, you can get the item value by this way,

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).sub`

Comment: i using this : `console.log('userId : ',JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).sub)` but it show me `userid : undefinde`

Comment: @Kianoush Did you debug this line and are you getting result  for JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"))?

Comment: @Kianoush: My answer is related to get object property value after object set successfully in local storage but you are getting error on service so my answer will not helpful at this point.

Comment: i find the answer . i decode the jwt token and i can access the id , but i have question about that , this way is secure ?

Comment: @Kianoush: localStorage.setItem("currentUser") will store the object into client browser side. It would be good to decrypt this object value thereafter store into browser. I am not sure about the security as you asked in question comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.loginService.LoginService(user).subscribe((data)=>{
  if(data)
  {
    console.log(data.sub);
    var userId = data.sub;  // use userId to store, etc.
  }
  this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl])
});
```

Retrieving values from LocalStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));  // to set values

var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));  // to get values from localStorage

console.log(user.sub); // tested in HTML code
```

Comment: `data` not have `sub` property

Comment: i using this : `console.log('userId : ',JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).sub)` but it show me `userid : undefinde`

Comment: @Kianoush what is the value after `console.log(data)`?

Comment: data have token

Comment: @Kianoush now, only you can help yourself: 

1) Check the value of in browser's `local storage`, check the `key`, try to parse the JSON using `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('your_key'))`

Comment: @Kianoush Solved it?

Comment: pooooof . not yet . i going crazy

Comment: @Kianoush Feel free to share the stackblitz example so i can try on it, with some sample data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185126/discussion-between-kianoush-and-prashant-pimpale).

Comment: i find the answer . i decode the jwt token and i can access the id , but i have question about that , this way is secure ?

Comment: Hmm finally! For jwt -> don't have an idea about it!